# Xcode ios Limiting characters in UIAlertView Textview

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextview

I've seen a lot of Tutorials on this, but they are for Objective C. I wanted to implement this feature into my app but wasn't sure how to do it.
Any Help is Great!

Comment: This kind of broad "tell me how to <xyz>" question is not a good fit for Stack Overflow. If you found tutorials explaning how to what you want using Objective-C then see if you can document what you think they are doing, and try to implement the same thing in Swift. If you can't, come back, post a link to the tutorial you're following, show the code you've written, and tell us what's going wrong with your code and then we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    let alert = UIAlertView(title: "Client id", message: "some title", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "ok")
     alert.alertViewStyle = .plainTextInput

    let textField: UITextField = alert.textField(at: 0)!
    textField.delegate = self

    alert.show()
}
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if (textField.text?.characters.count)! < 10
    {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDNSk.png